# File Is Not Deleting And Temp Files Is Not Being Rename

Tags: java, file

I am currently trying to copy all data will the exception of a singular line into a file name "temp" and having that file after all data is transferred into said file it should be rename to the old file that was deleted so it has update line with cars that are avalible.

```
    private static void removeCar(String vin, String make, String model, int year, int mpg, double price) {
        CarRespository carRespository = new CarRespository();
        String tempFile = "src/temp.csv";
        String filePath = "src/cars.csv";
        File oldFile = new File(filePath);
        File newFile = new File(tempFile);
        int line = 0;
        int deleteLine = -1;
        String currentLine = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < carRespository.getListOfCars().size(); i++) {
            if (carRespository.getListOfCars().get(i).getVinNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(vin)
                    && carRespository.getListOfCars().get(i).getMake().equalsIgnoreCase(make)
                    && carRespository.getListOfCars().get(i).getModel().equalsIgnoreCase(model)
                    && carRespository.getListOfCars().get(i).getYear() == year
                    && carRespository.getListOfCars().get(i).getMpg() == mpg
                    && carRespository.getListOfCars().get(i).getCarPrice() == price) {
                deleteLine = i+1;
                System.out.println(deleteLine);
            }
        }
            if (deleteLine == -1) {
                System.out.println("There is no valid match for the information provided!");
                customerWalkedIn();
            }
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line++;
                if (deleteLine != line) {
                    pw.println(currentLine);
                }
            }

            oldFile.delete();
            File dump = new File(filePath);
            newFile.renameTo(dump);

            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            fr.close();
            br.close();
            bw.close();
            fw.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

I tried what is posted above and the output was the files do not delete and if you continue to run the program the temp file will rewrite everything over and over again when run so the file will gain 99 lines when it should be losing one and not gaining any and the file also does not rename to cars.cvs.

Comment: Don't, ever, reference `src` from within your code, it won't exist once you've exported/packaged your app.  Close your resources BEFORE you try deleting/renaming them

Comment: You could probably benefit from using [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: It’s best to focus on one problem at a time. The likely reason deleting the old file isn’t working is that the reader is still open. I would recommend learning about the try-with-resources feature of Java and ensuring that the file deletion and renaming happens after the resources are closed.

Comment: And instead of just hoping that 'file.delete()' works, check the return value.  That means you can find out you have a problem when you have a problem, and directly, rather than when things go wrong as a consequence.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of your issues is the fact that your file resources are still "open".  You should make sure they are closed before you try deleting or renaming the files.

I would strongly recommend making use [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as this will take a lot of pain and additional "boiler plate" code out of the picture.

I would also check the return states of `File#delete` and `File#renameTo` to determine if those operations were successful or not and take appropriate action if they're not.

For example, you might be able to do something more like...

```
try {
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile, true))); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line++;
            if (deleteLine != line) {
                pw.println(currentLine);
            }
        }
    }
    File oldFile = new File(filePath);
    File newFile = new File(tempFile);

    if (!oldFile.exists()) {
        throw new IOException("Could not find old file " + oldFile);
    }
    if (!oldFile.delete()) {
        throw new IOException("Could not remove old file " + oldFile);
    }
    File dump = new File(filePath);
    if (!newFile.renameTo(dump)) {
        throw new IOException("Could not rename" + newFile + " to " + dump);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: the error given is : java.io.IOException: Could not remove old file cars.csv

Comment: @Coby So lots of reasons that this might occur.  First, verify that the file actually exists, as you're making use of a lot `String` paths (see `File#exists` as a starting point); Make sure that you don't have the file open else where in you code - it might even be worth rebooting your system just to be sure

Comment: I rebooted my system and ensured that the file does exist.

Comment: When also checking what the return they both return "false"

Comment: Did you use `File#exists` to check that the file's exist?  Don't just look at the file system, because your code could be doing a lot of weird things

Comment: So I did a really quick test on my system and had no issues removing the old file and renaming the temp file into it's place - but since I was able to do a simple isolated test, I would surmise that the issue is somewhere within your code

Comment: So it would be an issue within another class and or method?

Comment: I have also gone through the other methods that involve files and no other methods are causing the issue what else could it be?

Comment: The error is still it cannot remove old file with an IOException

Comment: Yes - it sounds like you're not closing the file some where - I would investigate updating your code to make use of `try-with-resources`

Comment: Put a breakpoint in this method, then check https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows (Assuming windows)

Comment: I fixed the issue you were correct I forgot to close a scanner that was accessing the file and putting said information into an arraylist ty for the help!

Comment: Yea.  Common problem for applications (Java or otherwise) on Windows.  You can't delete a file that is currently open.  Solution: close the file.  (Using the Java NIO classes instead of `File.delete` gives more diagnostic information but doesn't solve the problem.)